# Directory checksum with python?

Tags: python, file, filesystems, checksum

So I'm in the middle of web-based filesystem abstraction layer development. 
Just like file browser, except it has some extra features like freaky permissions etc.

I would like users to be notified somehow about directory changes. 
So, i.e. when someone uploads a new file via FTP, certain users should get a proper message. It is not required for the message to be extra detailed, I don't really need to show the exact resource changed. The parent directory name should be enough.

What approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server is Linux you can do this with something like [inotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/)

If the only updates are coming from FTP, then another solution I've used in the past is to write an add-on module to [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/features.html) that performs the "notification" once upload is complete.

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [How to quickly find added / removed files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479762/how-to-quickly-find-added-removed-files)

But if you can control the upload somehow (i.e. use HTTP POST instead of FTP), you could simply send a notification after the upload has completed. This has the additional benefit that it would be simple to make sure users never see a partial file.

Comment: I'd prefer FTP, since the files stored there are >200 MB each.

Comment: +1: Write the upload transaction.  Write your own FTP client that adds notification.

Comment: S.Lott: sounds like reinveting the wheel. Besides, my users would crucify me if I asked them to use my own client ;)

Comment: S.Lott: You only need to hook into the server (-> Van Gale's answer)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to monitor/check the last modification date of the working directory (using os.stat() for example).

Whenever a file in a directory is modified, the working directory's (the directory the file is in) last modification date changes as well.

At least this works on the filesystems I am working on (ufs, ext3). I'm not sure if all filesystems do it this way.