# How to quickly get whether a directory has changed using C++ without a monitoring thread or process?

Tags: winapi, directory

The change includes adding or removing files in the directory, or changes of its sub-directories. Is there any windows APIs which can get thus changes? I don't have a thread or process to monitor the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx)
- [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx)

also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682/how-to-see-if-a-subfile-of-a-directory-has-changed).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try [CDirectoryChangeWatcher](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/directorychangewatcher.aspx), it wraps the windows ReadDirectoryChangesW function up so it's easier to use.